# SwiftUI - Save results of a Form to JSON

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI, haven't coded in 15 years, but taking this on as a hobby. I am trying to take the results of a form and convert it to JSON so that I can save the output to a database. Can anyone provide some guidance?

```
var body: some View {
   Form {
      Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
          Toggle(isOn: $answer1) {
             Text("How would you like to answer this question?")
          }
          ...
      }
      ...
   }
   NavigationLink(destination: FormResult()) {
      Text("Submit")
   }
}
```

How do I make that form into a JSON? Does it need to be codable?

Answer (score 1):

You don't convert a Form directly to JSON. You rather bind the form to an object of a new type that you declare, and work with the object in code.

When you need to serialize the data, either for a network request or for storage, you can convert your object to JSON. If your type conforms to `Codable`, you can use `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder` to convert to/from its JSON representation.

So here's the concept:

```
struct Answer: Codable {
  var isOn: Bool = false
  var question: String
  var answer: String = ""
}

struct IntroForm: Codable {
  var nameAnswer    = Answer(question: "What's your name?")
  var meaningAnswer = Answer(question: "What's the meaning of life?")
}
```

```
@State var form = IntroForm()
var body: some View {
   Form {
      Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
          Toggle(isOn: $form.nameAnswer.isOn) {
             Text("How would you like to answer this question?")
          }
          if form.nameAnswer.isOn {
             TextField(form.nameAnswer.question, text: $form.nameAnswer.answer)
          }
          ...
      }
   ...
}
```

When you need to serialize, you can use `JSONEncoder`:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(form)
let jsonStr = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your data locally, the best option (for most simple cases) would be to use `CoreData`. It uses entities which are classes, so you don't have to convert your data to JSON.

```
class Item: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var id: String
    @NSManaged public var name: String
}
```

```
let item = Item(context: context)
item.id = form.id
item.name = form.name
try? context.save()
```

Where `context` is your global `managedObjectContext` (and preferably its child).